# Missing parameter for pluginExecutionFilter eclipse jpbm 7.12 project

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, jbpm

I have installed jbpm 7.12 server. I created an empty project in MySpace.

I cloned the proposed repo in jbpm-console (MySpace > Project name > Settings and cloned from the suggested URL in Global Settings).

I imported the project in Eclipse but when i do a project update (Maven > Update project), I got the following error

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'approvals'.
Missing parameter for pluginExecutionFilter. groupId, artifactId, versionRange and goals must be specificed, but found: groupId = 'org.kie'
artifactId = 'kie-maven-plugin'
versionRange = '7.12.0.Final'
goals = '[]'
```

Here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.alfasistemi.bpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>approvals</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>kjar</packaging>
  <name>approvals</name>
  <description></description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-jaxb</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.12.0.Final</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Eclipse. I have reverted back to 7.9.0-Final for just the kjar build plugin: kie-maven-plugin. You can still use 7.12.0-Final in the rest of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following plugin management to the build section in pom.xml

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[7.12.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>build</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```